# login credentials issue - remote mysql server (error 2002)

Tags: php, mysql

I am searching for solution to my problems for 2 days now, went through a lot of topics with similar problem, but I somehow didn't find the way to solve it.

So I am trying to connect to the remote server using mysql, but it seems I have a problem with login credentials.

```
$conn = mysql_connect("server", "username", "password");
if (!$conn){
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

the code is simple, but the way to get it to work is hard.

I was trying to replace "server" with `sub.domain.com:port` (where this link is the phpmyadmin link).

I tried putting the ip of a server, and some other stuff...
I set the privileges for user (grant all), in the phpmyadmin.

I really don't know what else could i do.
Any idea?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Is the server set up to accept remote requests?  May be a firewall issue

Answer (score 1):

The server needs to be the **MySQL** server and not the phpmyadmin link. You'll need to ask whoever is hosting your MySQL database for the server's name and port. `sub.domain.com` seems like a nameserver hostname and the default port of MySQL is `3306`.

`8060` indicates a possible APPX server, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the user has access from the calling IP.

So....
If your php code is hosted on the IP 1.1.1.1
And the user is  mysql_user

Make sure that there is a user registered for mysql_user@1.1.1.1

Make sure you can access MySQL on your server by doing a telnet... (where 2.2.2.2 is your sql server)

```
c:\>telnet 2.2.2.2 3306
```

If the server connects (no error messages) you are having the user issue I high-lighted above.